# combobox with multiple variables in one line, saving selection

Tags: c#, xml, winforms, linq

I'm taking XML, filtering and putting it into a combobox, and my issue is taking the selected combobox entry, and saving each individual piece. Here is some sample XML im using.

```
<SolutionString>  
    <Solutions>
        <Solution>
          <ID>1</ID>
          <Property>
            <Name>DriverSheave</Name>
            <Value>1VP34</Value>
          </Property>
          <Property>
            <Name>DriverBushing</Name>
            <Value>
            </Value>
          </Property>
          <Property>
            <Name>DrivenSheave</Name>
            <Value>AK49</Value>
          </Property>
          <Property>
            <Name>DrivenBushing</Name>
            <Value>
            </Value>
          </Property>
        </Solution>
        <Solution>
          <ID>2</ID>
```

...ect(ID 2, ID 3 and so on). After this im sticking these XML results into my combobox like this.

```
XmlDocument doc1 = new XmlDocument();
doc1.LoadXml(XmlString.ToString());
PTS.Library.VbeltDriveLibrary.Configurator Configurator = new PTS.Library.VbeltDriveLibrary.Configurator(doc1);
if (Configurator.SolveAndValidate())
{
    var solutions = Configurator.Results.ToXDocument();
    int i = 0;
    var indexesToChoose = new List<int> { 9, 8, 4, 5, 0, 2, 7, 6 };
    var cat = solutions
        .Descendants("Solution")
        .Select(x => new
        {
            ID = (string)x.Element("ID"),
            Properties = x.Elements("Property").Select(p => new
            {
                Name = (string) p.Element("Name"),
                Value = (string) p.Element("Value"),

                idx = (i < 11 ? i++ : i = 0)
            })
            .Where(y => indexesToChoose.Contains(y.idx))
            .OrderBy(z => indexesToChoose.FindIndex(p => p == z.idx))
            .ToList()
        });

    var items = cat
        .Select(s => new
        {
            ID = s.ID,
            Text = string.Format("{0}. {1}", s.ID,
            string.Join(", ", s.Properties
                               .Select(p => string.Format("{0} = {1}",
                                   p.Name,
                                   p.Value ?? "(null)"))))
        }).ToArray();
    comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Text";
    comboBox1.ValueMember = "ID";
    comboBox1.Items.AddRange(items);
```

Finally, i want to be able to take this selection,(this is the selected items in the combobox)

> 1. Cost = 1072.93, ActualDrivenShaftSpeed = 900/1073, Belt = B84, BeltQty = 5, DriverSheave = 5MVP70B84P, Comment2 = Correct tension for this drive (1.31 lb. should deflect belt 0.48 in.) will have 30 lb. 'running' Hub Load, DrivenSheave = 5MVB70R, ActualServiceFactor = 40.63, ActualCenterDistance = 30.8

and filter each piece out into a variable, for example,

```
string ActualCenterDistance = 30.8
```

Obviously i can put the whole selection into a string easily with a simple `combobox.selectedText`, however putting each piece into individual strings (or any other var) is my issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like a bad design for me.

Consider instead of using anonymous type here:

```
.Select(x => new
            {
                ID = (string)x.Element("ID"),
                Properties = x.Elements("Property").Select(p => new
```

just create instance of your own class which could be like:

```
public class MyItem
{
    public string ID;
    public List<Tuple<string, string>> Properties;

    public string GetProperty(string name)
    {
        if (Properties == null)
            return null;

        var item = Properties.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Item1 == name);
        return item == null ? null : item.Item2;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Join(", ", Properties
            .Select(p => string.Format("{0} = {1}",
                p.Item1,
                p.Item2 ?? "(null)")));
    }
}
```

in this case (since I've transferred logic of concatenation Name/Value of properties to `ToString` method override of `MyItem` class) - you can fill combobox with items having type of `MyItem`, and you will be able to access all your data easily like:

```
var item = comboBox1.SelectedItem as MyItem;
string x = item.GetProperty("DriverSheave");
```

Changes to be made with the code:

```
var items = solutions.Descendants("Solution")
    .Select(x => new MyItem
    {
        ID = (string)x.Element("ID"),
        Properties = x.Elements("Property").Select(p => new
        {
            Name = (string)p.Element("Name"),
            Value = (string)p.Element("Value"),

            idx = (i < 11 ? i++ : i = 0)
        })
        .Where(y => indexesToChoose.Contains(y.idx))
        .OrderBy(z => indexesToChoose.FindIndex(p => p == z.idx))
        .Select(z => new Tuple<string, string>(z.Name, z.Value))
        .ToList()
    }).ToArray();


comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Text";
comboBox1.ValueMember = "ID";
comboBox1.Items.AddRange(items);
```

Note: this is essentially important to have some custom class as `Item` for combobox, because in the case of anonymous type being used you will not be able to access its fields when taking object from `combobox.SelectedItem`.

Comment: how would i be able to filter between the items when i do the `combobox.SelectedItem`? i want to be able to take each piece of the `selectedItem` and place it into its own string or variable if possible, i may just be missing it in your answer.\

Comment: @AndrewKucenski `comboBox1.SelectedItem as MyItem` - will be one of `MyItems` used to fill combobox. So you can its `Properties` field and made whatever you want with this list. In your example from question - just find in this list tuple having `Item1` (we've put "Name" of properties from xml there as you remember) and return this tuple.Item2. It's better to add some helper method into `MyItem` class, say "GetProperty".

Comment: okay so with that list ill be able to simply take take say, Cost = 100, out ? Also thanks for such a detailed answer.

Comment: I've made some updates to the answer, have a look - this might help you to understand how to access selected item property you need.